# Regex for single line comments

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to identify a comment. It has to start with `//` and end with a new line or a `*)` pattern.

For now, I manage to get this `(\/\/)([^\n\r]+)`, but I am unsuccessful to add the `*)` pattern.

Any tips?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: Tip: don't try to parse source code with a Regex. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/179910).

Comment: What happens if `//` appears in the middle of a string `"some // stuff"`?

Comment: I removed the second question, I found the solution \"(\\.|[^"])*\"
But im still having trouble with the first one.
Galik if a comment in a string, the comment is ignored

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm totally copyrighting that line :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can't have it.  It's mine muhahaha ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Pretty sure it was mine first matey! #thief #lawsuit #arbitration #settlement #millions #retirement

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not after I stole it ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Next time someone tries to defend digital piracy by claiming that the original is not actually removed from the original owner, I shall point them to this conversation 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this:
[`^\/\/[^\n\r]+(?:[\n\r]|\*\))$`](https://regex101.com/r/wzWGn2/1)

Matches

- `^` Beginning of the string
- `\/\/` Match two forward slashes
- `[^\n\r]+` Match not a newline or a carriage return 1 or more times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[\n\r]|\*\)` Match a newline or a carriage return or *)
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` The end of the string

Edit:

Updated according to the comments, this is the final regex:

[`\/\/[^\n\r]+?(?:\*\)|[\n\r])`](https://regex101.com/r/nzL8pi/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(\/\/)(.+?)(?=[\n\r]|\*\))`.

`?=` means the last group is a positive lookahead. It only assert the following characters can match the new-line-or-`*)` pattern. If you want to match the new-line-or-`*)` pattern as well, just remove `?=`.

`.+?` means lazy matching, i.e. matching characters as few as possible. So for string such as `// something *) something *)`, it will stop matching before the first `*)`.

Note this pattern does not match `//\n` (your previous regex does not as well) because `+` means at least one characters. If you want to match such string, use `*` instead of `+` in the regex.

Finally, although you can use regex to parse such single line comments, as Jerry Coffin said in comment, don't try to parse programming source codes using regexes, because the language constituted by all legal source codes is commonly not a regular language.

Comment: Thanks your answer is perfect. I added the * to match empty comments. Thank you very much

Comment: This is a good approach. it is even better without the group tokens ```(...)``` as it is easier to evaluate the matches with a regex library built in a programming language: ```\/\/.*(?=[\n\r]|\*\))```

Answer (score 0):

extendind the answer of @the-fourth-bird if you need to find a block of single lines of comments, something like this changing 3 for the number of lines, should help to find a bigger blocks

```
^(\/\/.*[\r\n]){3}$
```

And if trying to find a block of comment with /** */ [here](https://blog.ostermiller.org/finding-comments-in-source-code-using-regular-expressions/) explain a few ways.