# Script to detect and save single line comments into an array for javascript files

Tags: javascript, coding-style, comments, eslint, eslintrc

I want to write a script that takes a javascript file and iterate through it line by line and check for single-line code comments. If there are any then push it to array and return that array.

**For Example:**

```
const array=[1,2,3,4,5];
//This comment needs to be detected and pushed to a new array
```

I have searched a lot about it and work through the **Eslint(JS linter)** but there is not any rule for single-line-comment but do have a rule for block-comment.

Comment: you can read the whole file and as soon as you get two consecutive // you can start populating the array until you find \n character. try it and post your code here if you run into problems

Comment: you can also use regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178646/regex-for-single-line-comments

Comment: Ok. I am currently working on this specific task. Thanks for feedback!