# RegEx to remove any comments from a JS file

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to create a script that will remove any `//` and `/**/` comments from JS files.

The script is currently consists of two regular expressions that are executed one after another. The problem is that it breaks in one specific case and I don't currently know how to fix it.

```js
var input = `
//
// Line comments
//

// aaa

alert("// xxx");

alert(x); // bbb

// ccc

//
// Block comments
//

/*
 * aaa
 * bbb
 */

/* ccc */

/**/ alert(x); /**/

alert("/* xxx */");

alert('/* yyy */');
`;

// removing line comments
input = input.replace(/("[^"]*\/\/.*?")|\/\/(?:.|\r?\n)*?(?:\r?\n|.*)?/g, "$1");

// removing block comments
input = input.replace(/(["'][^"']*\/\*.*?\*\/[^"']*["'])|\/\*(?:.|\r?\n)*?\*\//g, "$1");

console.log(input);
```

The output from the snippet above is wrong. The line that causes the problem is

```js
alert("// xxx");
```

The second regex treats the closing quotation mark in that line as the opening one and starts processing from this point. Here is a live demo: https://regexr.com/5n27q

How to fix it?

Credits:

- [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66301705)
- [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49178646)
- [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13014947)

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. Don't reinvent the wheel and utilize a package like `gulp-strip-comments` that already does this.
2. Or look at the source code of `gulp-strip-comments` and see how they match every possible form of comment from multiline, to inline, to minified etc. ([Source code](https://github.com/RnbWd/gulp-strip-comments))

`Gulp` is your friend if you're trying to "transpile" your JavaScript files. (:

Comment: I'm not familiar with Node and software that is based on it. I see that there are only two JS files in that repository, [index](https://github.com/RnbWd/gulp-strip-comments/blob/master/index.js) and [mainSpec](https://github.com/RnbWd/gulp-strip-comments/blob/master/test/mainSpec.js), and it seems they don't contain any regular expressions. If you or someone else knows *where exactly* I should see, I would be appreciated for this information.

Comment: The original component used in `gulp-strip-comments` seems to be `decomment` package: https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment They don't use much of RegEx - and that was my point about how you may not want to do that. You could use decomment in your browser's Javascript - there should be no issues. RE: Node - it runs on V8, which runs WebKit - and WebKit is what Chromium is based on (you see WebKit everytime you go to Developer Tools of Chrome for example.) Same platform, just different usage & use case.